# C# Converting TIFF JPEG compression to TIFF CompressionCCITT4 gives a lot of noise

Tags: c#, compression, noise

For a OCR engine I need to feed the OCR engine with TIFF files with CCITT4 Compression.
Our scanner outputs TIFF files with JPEG compression. I want to convert these files with C#, using System.Drawing.Imaging.

This results in images with a lot of Noise. How can I reduce the noise?

My Code:

```
        List<byte[]> fRet = new List<byte[]>();
        ImageCodecInfo fImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/tiff");
        EncoderParameters fEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(3);
        fEncoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);
        fEncoderParameters.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.ScanMethod, (int)EncoderValue.ScanMethodNonInterlaced);
        fEncoderParameters.Param[2] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.RenderMethod, (int)EncoderValue.RenderNonProgressive);

        //

        Image fOrgTiff = Image.FromStream(pInputTiff);
        Guid objGuid = fOrgTiff.FrameDimensionsList[0];
        FrameDimension objDimension = new FrameDimension(objGuid);
        int frameCount = fOrgTiff.GetFrameCount(objDimension);
        for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            fOrgTiff.SelectActiveFrame(objDimension, i);
            fOrgTiff.Save(ms, fImageCodecInfo, fEncoderParameters);
            ms.Position = 0;
            fRet.Add(ms.GetBuffer());
        }
        return fRet;
```

Comment: Is the original JPEG noisy or is the noise introduced by the conversion?  A simple median filter might do a pretty good job.

Comment: My guess is that you're getting a diffusion algorithm converting from JPEG to a binary image format. You need a thresholding or segmentation algorithm instead. Post all the possible parameters for your encoder.

Answer (score 1):

As [Brannon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1208289/brannon) said, Ccitt4 is a binary format (black/white) so your image is automatically binarized.
The documentation says: "[The Ccitt3, Ccitt4, and Rle require that the PixelFormat value be set to **BlackWhite**. Setting the PixelFormat to any other value resets the Compression property value to Default.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.tiffcompressoption.aspx)"

You can try to reduce the noise by choosing a better binarization threshold. You can look at algorithms provided by open-source imaging libraries like [AForge.Net](http://www.aforgenet.com/) or [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).